# Can we use bindActionCreators() on redux Action Creators defined in a class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I have defined Redux action creators inside a class in the following manner:

```
export class ActionCreator {

    login() {
        return { type: 'LOGIN_STATUS' };
    }

    fbLoginStatusOK(user) {
        return { type: 'LOGIN_OK', user };
    }
}
```

Then inside a React components I am using them like this:

```
class Login extends React.Component {

    login(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        a = new ActionCreator(); // Simplified
        dispatch(a.login());
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <p>
                    <a href="#" onClick={this.login}>Login</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

How can I use bindActionCreators on the '***ActionCreator***' class or its object?

(So that every action creator is wrapped into a dispatch call so they may be invoked directly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bindActionCreators` uses `Object.keys` to iterate all function properties of an object and wrap them with a `dispatch()` call.
In your case, even if you use something like `bindActionCreators(new ActionCreator())` it won't work, because `Babel` transpiles methods to non-enumerable properties.

A possible solution might be declaring all methods in the constructor:

```
class ActionCreator {
    constructor() {
        this.login = () => ({ type: 'LOGIN_STATUS' });
    }
}
```

but that would miss the point.

Another possibility is to create your own utility, which would be similar to `bindActionCreators` but would use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` instead of `Object.keys`. However, you should be cautious here and make sure you only wrap the methods you need (ignore `constructor`, for example).

I'm also wondering what's your motivation? isn't a bit of an overhead using a class instead of a plain object?

Comment: Since React is class based, I was just trying to put class wrappers on Redux part wherever possible.

Comment: I wouldn't call React "class-based", but simply "modular". Also, don't forget that Redux is not necessarily coupled with React. From your example, I can't see an actual need for declaring a class and instantiating. Technically, it will also result in a larger codebase.

Comment: Then can we go for static method declerations in ActionCreator class and then use bindActionCreators(ActionCreator, dispatch) ?

Comment: I don't think it would help, as `Object.keys` will only return the object's own properties.

Comment: Got your point. Left out class instantiation and changed to explicitly dispatched static methods for now. Waiting for other opinions.